# getting key and value from a dictionary

Tags: python, arrays

am working on image processing. in that am printing the RGB values. i converted that images into a Grayscale image.so its returning black and while value like this (left= {0: 58, 255: 182}).here 0 represents to black and 255 represents to white.I need to get those black and white values separately and check whether white or black have higher values.

```
 unique, counts = np.unique(cropped_right, return_counts=True)
 mapColorCounts = dict(zip(unique, counts))
 print("right=",mapColorCounts)
```

its returning dict values. in that i need that key and values separately

the return:

```
{0: 218, 255: 426}
{255: 196}
{0: 51, 255: 189}
{0: 406, 255: 314}
{0: 47, 255: 193}
{0: 28, 255: 278}
{0: 286, 255: 632}
{255: 306}
{0: 15, 255: 85}
{0: 91, 255: 229}
```

and i need to find how many sets of key values is returning. because sometimes it returns 2 value and 1 values

Comment: so what exactly are you expecting? as output

Comment: i need that 0 and 255 values seperate

Comment: i find it hard to believe that you wrote this code you provided here by yourself yet are struggling to simply extract keys from a dictionary

Comment: i can do it from array and list. i dont know how to do with dictionary

Answer (score 0):

If you have the values as a dictionary, you can use `mapColorCounts.values()` to return the 255 and 0 values. To visualise, dicts are stored like so `yourDict = {key: value, key: value}` and in order to return the keys or values you simply run the respective `keys()` or `values()` methods on the dict

From here you can create a simple method to test the values:

```py
def whichColorGreater(inputDict):
    values = inputDict.values()

    for value in values:
        if len(value) > 1:
            if value[0] > value[1]:
                print("Black is greater")
            else:
                print("White is greater")
        else:
            print("White is greater")
```

Comment: it returns the whole value. i need seperate values

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `cropped_right` is binary, I think you can simplify to:

```py
has_more_white = (np.count_nonzero(cropped_right) / cropped_right.size) > 0.5
```

If you need the number of elements:

```py
nb_white_pixels = np.count_nonzero(cropped_right)
nb_black_pixels = cropped_right.size - nb_white_pixels
```